# Fix speed in omnet++ and sumo

Tags: omnet++

I have question. If I have road with three lane each lane has own speed like ( 80 , 100 , 120 )Km/h ... Then need to test the performance of any protocol like the AODV for VANET when the vehicle speed is 90 Km/h.. and the number of vehicle is 100 how can do this,mean to set fix speed for these cars. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the speed of a vehicle you can simply give it the aspired speed as maximum speed and prevent it from dawdling (which it does with the default model). An input route file could look like this:

```
<routes>
    <vType sigma="0" id="t1" maxSpeed="90"/>
    <vehicle id="v1" type="t1" depart="0" route="r1" departSpeed="max"/>
</routes>
```

Please note that this will set the maximum speed to 90m/s (as requested in the question) which means 324 km/h. Also the definition of the route `r1` is excluded here.

If you have multiple interacting vehicles however you cannot at the same time guarantee collision free simulation and constant speed and sumo will favor the first.

Comment: Thanks Micheal for your replay ... Plz i replayed on your answer as a second answer so i can explain to you what my route file has .. plz check and advice .. Also i was mean 90 Km/h  not m/s i corrected my question .. Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks Michael for your help. Actually in my route i have like this

<routes>

 <route id="r2" edges=" 194402098#0 194402098#1 248057688#0 248057688#1 "/>

<vType id="t2" accel="2.6" decel="3.0" sigma="0.5" length="5" minGap="2" maxSpeed="50" color="1,1,1"/> 

<flow id="f2" type="t2" route="r2" begin="0.00" period="1" number="100"/>

</routes>
I wrote my route file like this as groups .. so i need to set depart = 0 and departSpeed="max" in the flow ? and also can i using number instead of max like departSpeed="90" ?? Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need to set `depart="0"` when using flows. You can try to use a number instead of max but if the vehicle cannot be inserted with this speed because it does not fit the lane speed, an error will occur.